# Stored procedure that selects from multiple group the results then order each group in descending order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the list of tables:

[My Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opmhK.png)

I will like to create a stored procedure that will use the athleteId as parameter for the query and select all the columns in the result table and a few columns in each of the other tables Group the results by the EventName of the Event Table then order the groups by the Mark in descending order from the Result table and select the last record for each event.

I have search the net and tried various queries but cant seem to get the results I need.

This is hat I created. It retrieves all the info I need but I just don't seem to be able to group, order and select the lowest mark.

```
SELECT 
    a.Id as AthleteId, a.FirstName AS FirstName, a.LastName AS LastName, 
    a.BirthDate AS BirthDate, a.IsMale AS Male, 
    a.Phone AS Phone, a.Email AS Email,
    p.FirstName AS ParentName, p.LastName AS ParentSurname, 
    p.Phone AS ParentPhone, p.Email AS ParentEmail,
    ad.Street1 AS Street1, ad.Street2 AS Street2, ad.Town AS Town, 
    ad.Parish AS Parish, ad.Country AS Country,
    s.SchoolName AS School, s.Phone AS SchoolPhone, 
    s.[Location] AS SchoolLocation,
    c.FirstName AS CoachName, c.LastName AS CoachSurname, 
    c.Phone AS CoachPhone, c.Email AS CoachEmail,
    m.MeetName AS MeetName, 
    m.StartDate AS StartDate, m.EndDate AS EndDate, m.[Location] AS MeetLocation,
    e.EventName AS EventName,
    r.Mark AS EventMark, r.Wind AS Wind, r.PerfDate AS PerfDate 
FROM
    dbo.Result r
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Event] e ON e.Id = r.EventId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Meet m ON m.Id = r.MeetId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Athlete a 
JOIN
    dbo.Parent p ON p.Id = a.ParentId
JOIN 
    dbo.[Address] ad ON ad.Id = a.AddressId
JOIN 
    dbo.Coach c ON c.Id = a.CoachId
JOIN 
    dbo.School s ON s.Id = a.SchoolId
    ON a.Id = r.AthleteId
WHERE 
    r.AthleteId = @AthleteId
```

When I try adding the group by it shows an error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way to do this in SQL Server is:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
. . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by r.eventid order by r.mark desc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon but I am not sure how to implement it. Can you expand on your reply?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I figure it out. Thanks for the help